# Performance testing environment

Tags: performance, web-applications, jmeter, load-testing

How do you begin with setting a Load environment for an Enterprise application (traditional MVC application with connectivity to some dependent enterprise systems)? For example, it would be ideal to have similar amount of Servers with same configuration as Production environment, also the Database should have similar size and capacity as Production to make Load environment similar to Production.

This does not happen in many organization, and I have seen organization using a trimmed down version of Production infra for the Load testing. Does that seems to be correct approach? Can we run a load test on the trimmed down version of Prod infra? Will this approach produce the result that can be used to predict Production application performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to measure how many users / requests per second your application can support the only way of doing it is running your test against production or production-like environment.

There are some things you could check against a scaled-down environment, for example:

1. Running a [soak test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing), this way you can discover [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
2. Running a load test having [profiler tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry enabled on the application under test side, this way you will identify the slowest functions, largest objects, etc.
3. Running a database load test, this way you can find out [slow queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) subject to optimization

More information: [Performance Testing in a Scaled Down Environment. Part Two: 5 Things You Can Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-five-things-you-can-test/)